# Regex to replace double with single quotes if at beginning and end of matching string

Tags: php, regex

I need to set single quotes for a complete line right after a defined string.

```
cite: Lorem ipsum dolor
```

Should get

```
cite: 'Lorem ipsum dolor'
```

Therefore I'm using this regex:

```
$line = preg_replace('/cite:\s*\K(.*)?$/s', '\'$1\'', $line);
```

But I need some additional things: If there are already double quotes for the line - that means at the begining AND at the end (optionally plus some spaces) - it should be replaced with single quotes. If the double-quotes are somewhere in the middle, nothing should happen to them.

If there are already single quotes at the beginning or end of the line, nothing should be done with that line.

Single quotes in the middle of the line need to be escaped. As it is used in a YAML-file, the single quotes in the middle of a string has to be escaped by doubling the single quote ( `'` should get `''`).

Example:

```
cite: "Lorem ipsum dolor"
cite: Lorem ipsum "dolor"
cite: Lorem "ipsum" dolor
cite: "Lorem "ipsum" dolor"
cite: 'Lorem ipsum dolor'
cite: Lorem 'ipsum' dolor
```

which should result in the following:

```
cite: 'Lorem ipsum dolor'
cite: 'Lorem ipsum "dolor"'
cite: 'Lorem "ipsum" dolor'
cite: 'Lorem "ipsum" dolor'
cite: 'Lorem ipsum dolor'
cite: 'Lorem ''ipsum'' dolor'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use:

```
$line = preg_replace_callback('/cite:\s*\K([\'"]?)(.+?)\1\h*$/m', function($m) {
            return "'" . str_replace("'", "''", $m[2]) . "'"; }, $line);
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yW7oR3/3)

Comment: Wow great! I just corrected the post. Please have a look at the last example: If there are already single quotes in the middle of the line, they have to be doubled (escaping for yaml-document)

Comment: And I see if there is a/some space(s) at the end, it gets some trouble: `cite: "Lorem ipsum dolor" `

Comment: Can't show it in the question as spaces aren't shown. Just look here for the first example line: https://regex101.com/r/yW7oR3/4 There is only a blank space at the line after the quote. And this makes trouble.

Comment: I have already taken care of that. Check my modified answer and updated demo link above.